# Получить из строки подстроку (Java)

Tags: java

У меня есть строка типа

`Document || {{sfsdf32423dscsdc,, Vsemprivet, Type=5, zaranee spasibo, dcdscsd435345=[]}}`

Длина строки может быть разная, но в ней всегда будет `Type=X`, где `X` это числовое значение.
Мне нужен стринговый `X`.
Использовать можно только стандартные библиотеки Java 8.

Comment: Регулярные выражения помогут

Comment: я уже понял, что это regex, но пока не могу его написать(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex здесь это как из пушки по воробьям. Судя по постановке вопроса интересует именно реализация стандартными/алгоритмическими средствами. Коли так, то путь примерно такой:

1. Сначала ищем строку `Type=`, `int typeIndex=s.indexOf("Type=");` в этом случае `typeIndex` будет содержать начальный индекс слова `Type=` (первый который встретится)
2. Далее ищем первую запятую после индекса `typeIndex`: `commaIndex=s.indexOf(',', typeIndex);`
3. Искомое выражение `X` находится после окончания `Type=` и запятой, положение которой показывает `commaIndex`: `xSubstring=s.substring(typeIndex+"Type=".length(), commaIndex);`

Надеюсь ТС дальше уже сам закодирует, обложив код проверками если нет `Type=`, если `Type=` встречается несколько раз, ну и т.д.и т.п.

Comment: Для меня Ваше решение идеально, "Type=X," это уникальная не повторяющаяся подстрока. Протестировал на всех возможных событиях, работает отлично. Спасибо Вам большое.